# T-SQL Conversion error in T-SQL Merge statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to build an optimized Slowly Changing Dimension using the Merge statement in T-Sql. I have written the following code to handle SCD1 and SCD2 changes, and also normal inserts in the data table, with data coming from the source table, Name and Age are SCD1 columns, Animal and Blood are SCD2 columns:

```
DECLARE @LoadingDate DATETIME
SET @LoadingDate = '2012-08-20 14:23:29.827'

--Handle SCD1 Changes
MERGE INTO Table_2 AS DIM
 USING SourceTable AS SRC
 ON (DIM.ID1 = SRC.ID1
    AND DIM.ID2 = SRC.ID2)
 WHEN MATCHED
    AND (DIM.Name <> SRC.Name 
      OR DIM.AGE <> SRC.AGE)
    THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET DIM.Name = SRC.Name,
    DIM.Age = SRC.Age;

--Handle SCD2 Changes
INSERT INTO Table_2
    (ID1, ID2, --Business Key
     Name, Age, --SCD1 Columns
     Animal, Blood, --SCD2 Columns
     DateEffective, DateExpires)
 SELECT
    ID1, ID2, --Business Key
     Name, Age, --SCD1 Columns
     Animal, Blood, --SCD2 Columns
     DateEffective, DateExpires
FROM (
MERGE Table_2 AS DIM
 USING SourceTable AS SRC
 ON (DIM.ID1 = SRC.ID1
    AND DIM.ID2 = SRC.ID2)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT VALUES 
  (SRC.ID1, SRC.ID2,
   SRC.Name, SRC.Age,
   SRC.Animal, SRC.Blood,
   @LoadingDate, NULL)
 WHEN MATCHED 
   AND DIM.DateExpires IS NULL
   AND (DIM.Animal != SRC.Animal
    OR DIM.Blood != SRC.Blood)
   THEN UPDATE SET DIM.DateExpires = @LoadingDate
 OUTPUT $action Action_Out,
   SRC.ID1, SRC.ID2,
   SRC.Name, SRC.Age,
   SRC.Animal, SRC.Blood,
   @LoadingDate AS DateEffective,
   NULL AS DateExpires) AS MERGE_OUT
 WHERE MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE';
```

The code works fine with SCD1 changes(first part of the code), but it gives me the error:
[image]
The error appears when it tries to insert a new row, for which the business keys ID1 and ID2 don't match with any other row from the Data Table, and "Labus" is the value in the name field.

Both tables are designed like in the following picture, but the SourceTable doesn't have housekeeping columns:
[image]

I would really appreaciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: @Johan: I don't think you can design a nullable column as an identity column in SQL Server. So ID1 and ID2 could not be autoincrementing. One of the nvarchar datatypes is being implicitly converted to an int which is the cause of this issue.

Comment: Drop the Insert and just let the Select display.  Be sure you have the values for ID1, ID2, and name you expect.

Comment: If i drop the Insert i get the error:Msg 10729, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests an implicit nvarchar to int conversion gone wrong, the initial steps to troubleshoot this would be to explicitly cast all nvarchar and int values possible (as shown below) and then check if you still get the error.

If you don't get an error, then you can start removing the casts and zero in to the specific int or nvarchar field.

If you do get an error, this could be a more specific error helping you figure out which section of the code it is happening on.

```
DECLARE @LoadingDate DATETIME
SET @LoadingDate = '2012-08-20 14:23:29.827'

--Handle SCD1 Changes
MERGE INTO Table_2 AS DIM
    USING SourceTable AS SRC
    ON ( CAST(DIM.ID1 AS INT) = CAST(SRC.ID1 AS INT)
         AND CAST(DIM.ID2 AS INT) = CAST(caSSRC.ID2 AS INT)
       )
    WHEN MATCHED AND ( CAST(DIM.Name AS nvarchar(255)) <> CAST(SRC.Name AS nvarchar(255))
                       OR CAST(DIM.AGE AS nvarchar(255)) <> CAST(SRC.AGE AS nvarchar(255))
                     )
        THEN 
    UPDATE
          SET
            DIM.Name = CAST(SRC.Name AS nvarchar(255)) ,
            DIM.Age = CAST(SRC.Age AS nvarchar(255)) ;

--Handle SCD2 Changes
INSERT  INTO Table_2
        ( ID1 ,
          ID2 , --Business Key
          Name ,
          Age , --SCD1 Columns
          Animal ,
          Blood , --SCD2 Columns
          DateEffective ,
          DateExpires
        )
        SELECT  CAST(ID1 AS INT),
                CAST(ID2 AS INT) , --Business Key
                CAST(Name AS nvarchar(255)) ,
                CAST(Age AS nvarchar(255)) , --SCD1 Columns
                CAST(Animal AS nvarchar(255)) ,
                CAST(Blood AS nvarchar(255)) , --SCD2 Columns
                DateEffective ,
                DateExpires
        FROM    (
MERGE Table_2 AS DIM
    USING SourceTable AS SRC
    ON ( CAST(DIM.ID1 AS INT) = CAST(SRC.ID1 AS INT)
         AND CAST(DIM.ID2 AS INT) =  CAST(SRC.ID2 AS INT)
       )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
        THEN INSERT
          VALUES    ( CAST(SRC.ID1 AS INT) ,
                      CAST(SRC.ID2 AS INT) ,
                  CAST(SRC.Name AS NVARCHAR(255)),
                  CAST(SRC.Age AS NVARCHAR(255)),
                  CAST(SRC.Animal AS NVARCHAR(255)),
                  CAST(SRC.Blood  AS NVARCHAR(255)),
                      @LoadingDate ,
                      NULL
                    )
    WHEN MATCHED AND DIM.DateExpires IS NULL
        AND ( CAST(DIM.Animal AS NVARCHAR(255)) != CAST(SRC.Animal AS NVARCHAR(255))
              OR CAST(DIM.Blood AS NVARCHAR(255)) != CAST(SRC.Blood AS NVARCHAR(255))
            )
        THEN UPDATE
          SET       DIM.DateExpires = @LoadingDate
    OUTPUT
        $action Action_Out ,
        SRC.ID1 ,
        SRC.ID2 ,
        SRC.Name ,
        SRC.Age ,
        SRC.Animal ,
        SRC.Blood ,
        @LoadingDate AS DateEffective ,
        NULL AS DateExpires) AS MERGE_OUT
        WHERE   MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE' ;
    --...
    --...
    --...
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait! The OUTPUT of the last merge may not match the Select clause. Hence the Action_Out may be getting mapped to ID1, hence the implicit conversion attempt.

Try modifiying the OUTPUT clause like this:

```
OUTPUT
    $action Action_Out ,
    SRC.ID1 AS ID1,
    SRC.ID2 AS ID2,
    SRC.Name AS Name,
    SRC.Age AS Age,
    SRC.Animal AS Animal,
    SRC.Blood AS Blood,
    @LoadingDate AS DateEffective ,
    NULL AS DateExpires) AS MERGE_OUT
    WHERE   MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE' ;
```

Comment: I changed the ID1 and ID2 fields to nvarchar(255) in the table design to see if i get a match, but when i execute the script i get: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Basically, I used the alias in the SELECT columns.
(Composable DML still has room for improvements.)

Also, is there a reason why you are inserting additional records (for update action) into Table_2 again when you are already doing a Merge into Table_2 in the subquery?

```
DECLARE @LoadingDate DATETIME
SET @LoadingDate = '2012-08-20 14:23:29.827'

--Handle SCD1 Changes
MERGE INTO Table_2 AS DIM
    USING SourceTable AS SRC
    ON ( DIM.ID1 = SRC.ID1
         AND DIM.ID2 = SRC.ID2
       )
    WHEN MATCHED AND ( DIM.Name <> SRC.Name
                       OR DIM.AGE <> SRC.AGE
                     )
        THEN 
    UPDATE
          SET
            DIM.Name = SRC.Name ,
            DIM.Age = SRC.Age ;

--Handle SCD2 Changes
INSERT  INTO Table_2
        ( ID1 ,
          ID2 , --Business Key
          Name ,
          Age , --SCD1 Columns
          Animal ,
          Blood , --SCD2 Columns
          DateEffective ,
          DateExpires
        )
        SELECT  MERGE_OUT.ID1 ,
                MERGE_OUT.ID2 , --Business Key
                MERGE_OUT.Name ,
                MERGE_OUT.Age , --SCD1 Columns
                MERGE_OUT.Animal ,
                MERGE_OUT.Blood , --SCD2 Columns
                MERGE_OUT.DateEffective ,
                MERGE_OUT.DateExpires
        FROM    (
MERGE INTO Table_2 AS DIM
    USING SourceTable AS SRC
    ON ( DIM.ID1 = SRC.ID1
         AND DIM.ID2 = SRC.ID2
       )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
        THEN INSERT
          VALUES    ( SRC.ID1 ,
                      SRC.ID2 ,
                      SRC.Name ,
                      SRC.Age ,
                      SRC.Animal ,
                      SRC.Blood ,
                      @LoadingDate ,
                      NULL
                    )
    WHEN MATCHED AND DIM.DateExpires IS NULL
        AND ( DIM.Animal != SRC.Animal
              OR DIM.Blood != SRC.Blood
            )
        THEN UPDATE
          SET       DIM.DateExpires = @LoadingDate
    OUTPUT
        $action AS Action_Out ,
        SRC.ID1 AS ID1 ,
        SRC.ID2 AS ID2 ,
        SRC.NAME AS Name ,
        SRC.Age AS Age ,
        SRC.Animal AS Animal ,
        SRC.Blood AS Blood ,
        @LoadingDate AS DateEffective ,
    NULL AS DateExpires) AS MERGE_OUT ( ID1, ID2, Name, Age, Animal, Blood,
                                        DateEffective, DateExpires )
        WHERE   MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE' ;
```

Comment: This stil gives the same conversion error, after i cover the error that appears if i don't put Action_Out in the list after Merge_Out.

Comment: I am not very good at T-Sql. I took the code from http://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/ , the fifth video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB27rN7PQi8 and adapted it to my probelm. The insert of the lines that were also updated is necessary since thats how Slowly Changing Dimesion Type 2 attributes work, keeping history("Update" with expiry date) and inserting a new line with the newly changed data.